# How to pack .NET Core projects recursively without running pack on the entire solution?

Tags: .net-core, nuget

I have a solution of a hundred plus .NET Core projects. Not all of them needs to be packed, but only those which are transitive dependencies of a few special projects.

However, when I run `dotnet pack` it attempts to pack all kinds of projects that it should not and there are errors here and there. I would like instead to run pack on the special projects only in a recursive fashion, so that only them and their transitive dependencies (project references, of course) are packed.

I figured I can implement it by scripting around the `dotnet list reference` command, but it does not sound right. There must be a better way to do it.

**EDIT 1**

The solution must work on the command line where we have dotnet and msbuild and possibly nuget, but no VS IDE.

Comment: Docs for 'dotnet pack' says it makes 'dotnet build' first. For me, 'dotnet build' builds (if needed) all dependencies first. Are you really sure that running 'dotnet pack' on single project does not build referenced projects? May be they are already built and previous build results are used?

Comment: Indeed all the dependent projects are built, but packed is only the project you specify in the command line. Building and packing are 2 different things. Besides, you can run dotnet pack --no-build and nothing would be built. Only packed.

Comment: Ah, you want to pack all dependent "packable" projects too? Missed that. Check "Generate nuget package on build" in project properties (package tab). It creates .nupkg file during "dotnet build".

Comment: On what project do I check this? I have a hundred plus of projects. Not all of them are dependencies of the special projects I want to pack.

Comment: On every project that should be "packable". Say, you have project A, B, C and D; and B and C depends from A; and D depends from C. You want to build-pack D, and during this you want to pack C, but does not want to build\pack B because it broken. You set "generate nuget on build" at B, C and D, and then run "dotnet build" for D. To build it dotnet will automatically "dotnet build" A and C. So, you will have A, C and D built, and C and D auto-packed during build.

Comment: So, we need to manually mark all the relevant projects. That does not really answer my question - how to pack recursively. What you suggest is pack all that needs to be manually and then run dotnet pack on the entire solution, not the project. Not exactly what I am asking for.

Comment: If you have "packable" and "unpackable" projects - you should mark "packable" anyway. But I don't offer to pack entire solution after that. I offer to "build" some projects you need and this will auto-build their dependencies and auto-pack (during build) them if they are "marked packable".

Comment: When we are packing a single project using `dotnet pack` I have never witnessed anything else packed. Now maybe VS IDE does something extra, but there is no VS IDE on a build agent. Only dotnet and msbuild and I suppose nuget. The solution must work on the command line. I will make sure it is clear in the post.

Comment: I was writing about auto-packing during "dotnet build" (not dotnet-pack), on one project and it will auto-pack all dependencies too (all that "marked" for packing). If this is not what you want - so you need to improve your question somehow.

Comment: OK, I get it now. By adding `<GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>` to the csproj file we get the build generate the NuGet package. That merits an upvote. Can you arrange it as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can modify your project settings to generate *.nupkg file during `dotnet build`, without explicit `dotnet pack` call. And as soon as dependencies get builded automatically when "parent" project builds - you will receive nuget packages prepared for all dependencies too when you run `dotnet build` for "parent" project only.

For each project that should produce nuget package add this lines into csproj file:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Or, instead, you may enable checkbox "Generate NuGet package on build" from Visual Studio, in project properties ("Package" tab) - this will add same line into project file.

Comment: The only reason why I am not accepting it as an answer is because in a solution of 100+ projects manually marking the dependencies of the special projects is tedious. The tendency would be to put this in Directory.Build.props, but then all the projects will have nupkg generated and some produce annoying NuGet warnings. Also, this approach does not allow to build **without** packaging. So, definitely an upvote, but I hope for a better approach.

Comment: You don't need to "mark dependencies" in 100 projects. You should mark projects that should be nuget-packed when built (i.e. mark all class libraries, but does not mark console projects, webapps etc). Then you build one "top-level" app, and all "marked" dependencies of it will be nuget-packed too, automatically.